# UIAlertview clicked button at index delegate method not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

Am new to AlertViews with actions. Have set mine up as in the examples I found here including setting the delegate method in my .h, but when I debug find that it is not reaching my clickedButtonAtIndex method. Probably missing something simple :-/ Any help solving this would be appreciated, thanks.
Here's my code:

.h file

```
@interface LineDetailViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

. m file:

```
- (IBAction)removeLineButton:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSString * requestSubmitText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey Bro are you sure you want to remove this line you created, it will also remove all the reviews attached and can not be undone?"];

    UIAlertView *removeLineRequest = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WARNING!!"
                                                          message:requestSubmitText
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Remove It"
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",nil];
    [removeLineRequest show];

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    //if (buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex]){
    if (buttonIndex == 0){
        NSLog(@"Cancel button pressed");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"other button pressed");
    }
}
```

Comment: just set delegate:self instead of nil... and it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set delegate to `self`

```
UIAlertView *removeLineRequest = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WARNING!!"
                                                          message:requestSubmitText
                                                         delegate:self // <- here
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Remove It"
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `removeLineRequest.delegate = self`.

Answer (score 1):

While creating your alert view set your delegate to self . And you have already implemented the UIAlertViewDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, just set the `delegate` to `self` instead of `nil`.
Some additional info,

`UIAlertView` and `UIAlertViewDelegate` have been deprecated. As per the documentation,

> `UIAlertView` is deprecated. Use `UIAlertController` with a `preferredStyle` of `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert` instead.

Relevant tutorial [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html)